# monacaを利用したiosへのプッシュ通知

Tags: ios, monaca, push-notification

お世話になります。
MONACAのIDEからプッシュ通知を配信しているのですが、パターンによって動作が違います。
どなたか同じような現象に合われた方はいないでしょうか？

A:デバッガー宛て＆デバッガー起動中
　monaca.cloud.Push.setHandler内のalert表示
B:デバッガー宛て＆デバッガー非起動
　メッセージ表示　＝＞　アプリ起動　＝＞　monaca.cloud.Push.setHandler内のalert表示
C:アプリ宛て＆アプリ起動中
　表示なし
D:アプリ宛て＆アプリ非起動
　メッセージ表示　＝＞　アプリ起動

パターンで挙動が違っても良いのですが、特に上記のCパターンはNGです。
何か情報がありましたら、お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

以下のコードで問題が出ていましたが、
monaca.cloud.Push.setHandler(function(data) {
　　alert(data.mess);
});

次のように変更して解決しました。
monaca.cloud.Push.setHandler(test);
function test(data) {
　　alert(data.mess);
}